# Base de datos de transistores en javascript

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de base de datos de transistores, que al buscar en un cuadro de texto el codigo del transistor y apretando el boton de buscar, lo busque en el array que tengo con sus datos ya cargados y lo muestre.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Base de Datos de Transistores</title><font color=blue><center><H1>Base de Datos de Transistores</h1><br><h3>Ingresar el codigo del transistor o parte de ella y pulsar el botón 'Buscar'</h3></center>
</head>
<body bgcolor = 99CCFF>
<form>
<div align="center">
<br> <center> <input type= "Text" value="2N2222A" size=36 id="texto" backcolor=black> <br>
<input type="button" value="Buscar" id="boton"></div>
 </form>
<script language = "javascript">

var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
boton.addEventListener("click",botonclick);
var bolsa = new Array();
bolsa.push("2N1305 GE-P 30V 0.3A 0.15W 5MHz");
bolsa.push("2N1307 GE-P 30V 0.3A 0.15W");
bolsa.push("2N1613 SI-N 75V 1A 0.8W 60MHz");
bolsa.push("2N1711 SI-N 75V 1A 0.8W 70MHz");
bolsa.push("2N2166 SI-P 15V 50mA 0.15W 10MHz");
bolsa.push("2N2219A SI-N 40V 0.8A 0.8W 250MHz");
bolsa.push("2N2222A SI-N 40V 0.8A 0.5W 300MHz");
bolsa.push("2N2223 2xSI-N 100V 0.5A 0.6W");
bolsa.push("2N2223A 2xSI-N 100V 0.5A 0.6W");

function botonclick(){
var estaba = 0;
cadena = ("Coincidencias encontradas para ");
var valor = texto.value.toUpperCase();
var i;
for ( i= 1; i<=bolsa.length; i++){
if (bolsa[i].indexOf(valor) == 0) {
estaba = 1;
break;
}
}
if (estaba ==1) 
{
document.write (  cadena + "<font face=verdana size=2><b>"  + valor + "<br></b>" );
document.write (bolsa[i]);
document.write ("<br><b><font color=0000FF>Para realizar otra busqueda, pulsar el boton atrás en el navegador</font></b></marquee>");
}
else
{
document.write ("<font face=verdana size=2>No se hallaron coincidencias para <b>"  + valor + "</b>");
document.write ("<br><br><b><font color=0000FF>Para realizar otra busqueda, pulsar el boton atrás en el navegador</font></b>");
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: por ahi detecto un error en tu if, el signo de comparación es `===` y tu solo estas usando `=` que es para asignar

Comment: var texto = texto.value.toUpperCase(); ??? como ahces para definir texto en la misma linea donde lo lees?

Comment: Ya arregle eso jeje. Me falta comparar bien el array para encontrar la busqueda asi lo muestre.

Comment: Y ahora que error tenes?

Comment: No uses un for con la posicion (x), te recomendaría que uses un forEach() para recorrer cada uno de los datos y poder compararlo sin tanto código.

Comment: Ya lo pude hacer funcionar con indexOf(). Lo que me falta por ultimo es poder mostrar todas las coincidencias encontradas y no solo una. Ejemplo: tengo el codigo 2N2223 y 2N2223A, cuando busco 2N2223 solo me aparece el 2N2223. Yo quiero que aparescan los dos, osea el 2N2223 y el 2N2223A. Creo que es por el break, pero nose como hacerlo. Recien empiezo en esto del javaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Agrego respuesta solucionando tu pregunta, modifique la salida para efectuar varias busquedas sin recargar la pagina:

```js
function botonclick(){
var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
var estaba = 0;
cadena = ("Coincidencias encontradas para ");

//console.dir(bolsa);
var subConjuntoResistores=filtroTransistores(texto.value);
//console.dir(subConjuntoResistores);
  document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML += '<div id="idChild">     '+ 'Salida:'+' </div>';

for(i=0;i<subConjuntoResistores.length;i++)
  {
 
  
  document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML += '<div id="idChild">     '+ subConjuntoResistores[i]+' </div>';
  }

}
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.addEventListener("click",botonclick);

const filtroTransistores = (subcadena) => {
   // console.log(subcadena);
  let query = subcadena.toUpperCase();
  return bolsa.filter(item => item.toUpperCase().indexOf(query) >= 0);
}


var bolsa = new Array();
bolsa.push("2N1305 GE-P 30V 0.3A 0.15W 5MHz");
bolsa.push("2N1307 GE-P 30V 0.3A 0.15W");
bolsa.push("2N1613 SI-N 75V 1A 0.8W 60MHz");
bolsa.push("2N1711 SI-N 75V 1A 0.8W 70MHz");
bolsa.push("2N2166 SI-P 15V 50mA 0.15W 10MHz");
bolsa.push("2N2219A SI-N 40V 0.8A 0.8W 250MHz");
bolsa.push("2N2222A SI-N 40V 0.8A 0.5W 300MHz");
bolsa.push("2N2223 2xSI-N 100V 0.5A 0.6W");
bolsa.push("2N2223A 2xSI-N 100V 0.5A 0.6W");
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Base de Datos de Transistores</title><font color=blue><center><H1>Base de Datos de Transistores</h1><br><h3>Ingresar el codigo del transistor o parte de ella y pulsar el botón 'Buscar'</h3></center>
</head>
<body bgcolor = 99CCFF>
<form>
<div align="center">
<br> <center> <input type= "Text" value="2N222" size=36 id="texto" backcolor=black> <br>
<input type="button" value="Buscar" id="boton"></div>

<div id='salida'></div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```